# How can I get rid of the hash tag in my AngularJS site URL?

Tags: angularjs, github, dns, cname, github-pages

I uploaded an AngularJS site to my `gh-pages` branch and pointed the DNS A records to 204.232.175.78. Now the site is live but I see a hash tag as part of the URL structure. Here are the two URLs one can see the home page of the site at

http://www.maxmythic.com/#/

http://siddhion.github.io/maxmythic_angular/#/

The URL I want visitors to enter and see in the address bar is simple **maxmythic.com**. If one enters [maxmythic.com](http://maxmythic.com) it redirects to http://www.maxmythic.com/#/.

How would I make the URL of the home page just [maxmythic.com](http://maxmythic.com) with out the **www.** and trailing **/#/**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the app's main module's config function, use the `html5mode()` function of the `$locationProvider`. Read these docs for more info: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$locationProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24locationProvider) and [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location).

Example:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

Comment: Hmm. Whenever I press refresh on any page on my site that is not maxmythic.com I get the Angular `404.html` page. Also, say I have clicked around on my site 5 times, press refresh, get the 404 page and then press back to get to the last working page, well, clicking back through my history still results in the `404.html` page unless I get back to my root URL maxmythic.com. Why is this happening? Should this be a new question?

Comment: Can you make a new question with the route setup (the `$routeProvider` in the app's `config()`) that you are using and link back to it here? I'm not sure if that's the problem but it might help. Also, please post anything else that might aid us in finding a solution...

Comment: UPDATE: I found another StackOverflow question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895675/angularjs-html5mode-refresh-page-get-404) that might help.

Comment: Here is my new question with as much info I have on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912543/getting-404-page-on-refresh-on-angularjs-site Thanks in advance :)